# c# combobox combine autocompletemode with drawitem

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I have a program that have combobox which have autocompletemode property, while also that combobox items each have diffrent color (drawitem brush) like word "Sky" is blue color, "Fire" is red color, etc.

When I select the combobox normally, the text will be colorful.
When I input a word (ex: `'F'`) combobox will show the word which begins with `'F'` (ex: "Fire", "Fire Truck") but the color is return to normal (black) and not red.

Here's sample code for autocompletemode and drawitem:

```
 public FColor()
 {
     InitializeComponent();

     cmbColor.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
     cmbColor.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
     cmbColor.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
}

private void cmbColor_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();

    string text = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();

    Brush brush;
    if (text.Equals("Sky") | text.Equals("Ice") | text.Equals("Cold"))
    {
        brush = Brushes.Blue;
    }
    else if (text.Equals("Fire") | text.Equals("Flame") | text.Equals("Volcano") | text.Equals("Fire Truck))
    {
        brush = Brushes.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        brush = Brushes.Yellow;
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, ((Control)sender).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
}
```

Comment: is cmbColor_DrawItem being called after the autocomplete?

Comment: Do you mean the color in the dropdown or in the display part of the combobox? For the latter you would have to set it somewhere (` cmbColor.ForeColor = Color.Red`..)